# How to call another property file?

Tags: properties, liferay, resourcebundle, liferay-6

I'm having two property file called sample.properties and sample1.properties in src folder at same level.

It is having some information like,

```
A1 = please call {sample1:name}
```

Here,
sample1 -> property file name
name -> key defined in sample1 like [name = abc]

I want to call sample1 property file , get value of name from that file and store it into the A1 key in sample.properties.

Is there any way to include and fetch value from other property file?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Mayur Patel

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, and why you need to access two properties files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't think you can do this. My understanding is that you can only provide one properties file per portlet.

What are you trying to achieve with this approach? Why can't you just use one properties file?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved same problem not by calling property file from the same but I used stringtokenzier to split that token n from that i get name of property file and i called that file from java code only.

actually I wanted to know is it poosible to achieve this..thanks for your ideas

Regards,
Mayur Patel